# How can I prevent a responsive menu from breaking my layout when the window is resized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I've updated my self-made responsive menu but I have a problem with the menu disappearing when resizing.

When I downsize my window below 1100px width and open the responsive menu, everything is fine. However when I close the responsive menu Jquery applies a display: none inline attribute.

This makes my screen disappear when I resize back to full width.

I've updated my codepen with the javascript below. Is this a good solution or can somebody help me improve this little responsive menu?

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXjXBj)

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    if (viewportWidth > 1100) {
        $('.navigational-menu').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: There is a dedicated site for [codereview.se], but they require *working* code. You're reporting a bug in your code, so please try to include a small test-case *in the post itself* so that others may examine your code and help you find the problem. See: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Use css media queries to force state with a class toggle instead of .hide()/.show() and a lot of your headaches will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is just part of adapting a site to be responsive.

First off, I'd recommend using media queries instead of javascript to do it.  Start by adding in rules for the different widths you'll be defining for, so if it goes below 1100px, you'll need to have

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) { /* Changes to your CSS for widths below 1100px will go here */}
```

What you want to do is resize your window below that width, and then see everything that "breaks" or needs to be redone with new CSS rules, and make those changes.  You'll probably need to change the menu sizes, maybe font-sizes (depending on how you have it set up).  But what I find to be the easiest, is to open up your browsers CSS Element Inspector / CSS Editor, and make those changes on the fly as you're resizing your browser.  Then, just transfer those changes to your main code, and keep going for the lower widths.   Chances are this one rule for under 1100px won't be enough, and you'll have to create a few to ensure it looks good at all widths.  So say, once you get to 800px, you'll want to further update some elements, you just

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 800px) { /* Changes to your CSS for widths below 800px will go here */}
```

And do the same thing.  Keep going until your site works well at all widths, and your site will be responsive.

From the look of your question though, it seems as though you're looking for a magic bullet to make the menu work automatically responsively... unfortunately, that's not how it works, and you're going to have to code in the changes at each level to make it look how you'd like.

Good luck!